# Help with triple integrals and upward flux of vector field

Tags: definite-integrals, vector-fields

I'd like to ask you for help with these three problems I found.

1. Evaluate the volume of the solid region
   $R = \{(x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 \le  z \le 4 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}.$
2. Evaluate the volume of the solid that lies below the paraboloid $z = x^2+y^2$ and inside the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + (z-2)^2 = 9.$
3. Evaluate the upward flux of the vector field
   $F(x,y,z) = (x+y)\mathbf{i} + (y-z)\mathbf{j} + z^2\mathbf{k}$
   through the part of the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ cut off by the plane $z = 2.$

My main problem is that i can't figure out regions of integration. I'd really appreciate if someone would show me some way to find the region so I can get the scheme and be able to use it in next problems.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use cylindrical coordinates in all cases.

For 1, you get $$r^2\le z\le 4-r$$
Just focus on the $r$ terms. This will give you the integration range for $r$ as the interval between $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt {17}}{2}$, so you can find then $z$.

For 2, the lowest $z$ is $0$ (bottom of the paraboloid), and the top is $z=5$ (top of the sphere). Note that you have two integration regions, depending if the radius of the paraboloid, or the radius of the sphere is larger. By radius I mean the radius in cylindrical coordinates. The intersection is given by
$$x^2+y^2=r^2=z=9-(z-2)^2$$
If I did not make any mistake, the positive solution is $\frac{3+\sqrt{29}}{2}$

For 3, you have a disk of radius $\sqrt 2$ in the plane $z=2$

Comment: Okay, I found out how to do first and second one. Can You please show me step by step how to do the third one? Because I've got no idea how to do it.

Comment: The integration area is $x^2+y^2=2$ and $z=2$. $F(x,yz)$ has three components, and for flux you only need the component along the normal. The normal vector to plane $z=2$ is $\bf{k}$, so you need to integrate $2^2$ along the surface of the disk.